# Join three tables MySQL Where

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

First, I realize there are other similar questions, I have read through many of them and I cannot figure this out.

I have three tables like so.

```
urilist
----------------
rowid | uri
1000      xyz
1001      abc
1002      cde
1003      fgh

wordlist
----------------
rowid | word
1      word1
2      word2
3      word3
4      word4

wordlocation2
----------------
uriid | wordid
1001      1
1001      2
1001      3
1001      4
```

Table a hold uris. Table b holds words. Table c is a lookup table where you can see every word associated with a uri or vice versa.

I need to return the words for a given uri. so for uri `abc` I need words `word1,word2,word3,word4`.

This was my latest attempt.

```
select word from wordlist join wordlocation2 on wordlist.rowid = 

wordlocation2.wordid 
left join urilist on wordlocation2.uriid = urilist.rowid 
and urilist.uri =  "a uri address";
```

This returned thousands of unrelated answers. I'm not really sure of the best way to do this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us look at your query result by selecting *. I have used 'a uri address' as given by you for demonstrating regarding LEFT JOIN

Query:

```
select * from wordlist join wordlocation2 on wordlist.rowid = wordlocation2.wordid left join urilist on wordlocation2.uriid = urilist.rowid and urilist.uri =  "a uri address";
```

This will fetch the below result

[image]

As you have done wordlocation2 LEFT JOIN urilist, even if there is no matching row for urilist, a value will come in the result by making the urilist value as NULL (this is the meaning of left join). In your case, you should not get any value if there is no matching row. So, use JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN.

```
select * from wordlist join wordlocation2 on wordlist.rowid = wordlocation2.wordid join urilist on wordlocation2.uriid = urilist.rowid where urilist.uri =  "abc";
```

I think the order of tables doesn't matter as everything is inner join here. I am always ready to correct myself if anyone gives some suggestion on this.

Answer (score 0):

This should be your query:

```
select l.word from urilist u
join wordlocation2 w on w.uriid = u.rowid
join wordlist l on l.rowid = wordid
where u.uri = 'some_uri'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
select u.uri, wl.word
from urilist u
join wordlocation2 wl2 on wl2.uriid = u.id
join wordlist wl on wl2.wordid = wl.rowid
```